# SQL Server 2012: IIF trouble with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server-2012, conditional-statements, iif

Not sure why I can't match all values.

```
IIf((Op IN ('O-O', 'SH', '') AND CtS = '' AND TRY_CONVERT(INT, DIS) >= 50), 'SP', 'NSP') AS SPS
```

Data

```
L_ID    CtS DIS    Op        SPS
---------------------------------------
50          74      O-O   NSP
85          68      O-O   SP
200         50      O-O   NSP
278         64.01   O-O   NSP
```

[See screenshot for output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM8mC.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: I thought IIF() was an Access/MySql thing. In Sql Server, you generally use CASE statements, which are part of the ansi standard. IIF() is not.

Comment: Ah... I see it was added for the 2012 edition. Still not part of the standard, though.

Comment: Not too sure, it will fix all the issues, but you may want to try `TRY_CONVERT(numeric(5,2), DIS)` or if `numeric(5,2)` isn't big enough something similar which is.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. Really appreciate it.